# What is DIR command a substitute of in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I know that I can use *DIR* to list the directory and *MKDIR* to create a new one. However, I learned today that one can (should?) use *New-Item -ItemType Directory "c:\pip*" instead, which, indeed, looks much more PowerShellish.

I'm not getting any hits when googling for the equivalent of *DIR*, though. Is *DIR* just *DIR*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dir | ls` == `get-childitem`.

You can figure out aliases using the get-alias command: `get-alias dir`. Aliases are used fairly frequently, for example, `gci` is an alias for `get-childitem` as well.